# Memory leak with Mathematica Graph functions

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, memory, resource-management

I am running Mathematica 13.2 on a Mac OS Monterey. I have a large code that manipulates graphs both in graph form and as adjacency matrices, computes some graph properties, and returns a list. It has been leaking memory and after some effort I was able to isolate the problem to the the built in function `GraphAutomorphismGroup`. Here is a simplified code that illustrates the problem.

I started a new notebook and executed the following:

```
In[8]:= Quit[];
In[1]:= $HistoryLength = 0;
In[2]:= Names[$Context <> "*"]
        MemoryInUse[]

Out[2]= {}

Out[3]= 81382952

In[4]:= Clear[leakyFunction];
        leakyFunction[vCount_Integer] := 
           GroupOrder[
                GraphAutomorphismGroup[
                    RandomGraph[{vCount, RandomInteger[{0, vCount(vCount-1)/2}]}]]];
In[6]:= Names[$Context <> "*"]
        MemoryInUse[]
Out[6]= {"leakyFunction", "vCount"}

Out[7]= 80525080
```

So far so good. Now I ran the function I just defined some number of times in a `Do` loop outputting memory used during intermediate steps.

```
    In[8]:= Do[If[Mod[n, 2000] == 0, Print["mem ", MemoryInUse[]];];
               leakyFunction[12], {n, 10000}]
    During evaluation of In[8]:= mem 84044168
    During evaluation of In[8]:= mem 86922688
    During evaluation of In[8]:= mem 89563816
    During evaluation of In[8]:= mem 92306328
    During evaluation of In[8]:= mem 95014752
```

You see memory in use steadily marching up. I checked to see if there are any lingering variables but there were none.

```
    In[9]:= MemoryInUse[]
            Names[$Context <> "*"]
    Out[9]= 94977216
    Out[10]= {"leakyFunction", "n", "vCount"}
```

Clearing system cache frees up only a fraction of the memory eaten up

```
    In[11]:= ClearSystemCache[]
             MemoryInUse[]
    Out[12]= 90687256
```

I even tried `CleanSlate[]` and for a good measure, `ClearInOut[]` even though I have set `$HistoryLengh = 0;` at the start. Neither of these helped

```
    In[13]:= Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"]
    In[8]:= CleanSlate[];
            ClearInOut[];
            MemoryInUse[]
    During evaluation of In[8]:=   (CleanSlate) Contexts purged: {Global`}
    During evaluation of In[8]:=   (CleanSlate) Approximate kernel memory recovered: 0 Kb
    Out[1]= 90889808
```

Finally, I tried clearing `InString` and `MessageList` even though again I had no good reason to think that memory is eaten up here

```
    In[2]:= Unprotect[InString, MessageList];
            Clear[InString, MessageList];
            Protect[InString, MessageList];
            MemoryInUse[]
    Out[5]= 90916984
```

Finally, removing every variable in the context did nothing to free up the space.

```
    In[6]:= Scan[Remove, Names[$Context <> "*"]]
            MemoryInUse[]
   Out[7]= 90941904
```

I am at a loss as to what to try. Nothing short of `Quit[]` seems able to free up the space eaten up. The offending function seems to be `GraphAutomorphismGroup`, removing the `GroupOrder` won't make the problem go away.

Could anyone explain to me why this is happening, and if there is any solution or workaround?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

A Wolfram Mathematica staff member got back to me regarding my report  and said that "there does appear to be a memory leak with GraphAutomorphism" and that "the developers don't have a workaround for this." I guess we will have to wait at least until the next version for the issue to be fixed.

Comment: Did you try reaching out to support@wolfram.com? Based on your description, sounds like a bug that would be hard to resolve at the user level.

Comment: @VictorK. yes I just submitted a help request. I am hoping that someone has encountered a similar issue and knows a workaround until the bug (if it is a bug) is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Also, technically you hasn't established that it's the GraphAuthomorphismGroup that leaks the memory, as it could also be one of the RandomGraph, RandomInteger, GroupOrder[

Comment: @VictorK. I actually tried the other possibilities before narrowing it down to GraphAutomorphismGroup. I should have stated that, but you also independently was able to establish that the issue is with GraphAutomorphismGroup. I regards to using MemoryConstrained, it's not ideal for what I'm trying to do if it aborts.

Comment: there seem to be two more graph functions that leak memory (see my update) - could you please add them to your report to Wolfram?

Comment: Ok, yes I will do a follow up to Wolfram with the two additional graph functions you found. P.S. I love your leakingQ function :)

Comment: @Kassa: It is good that you brought up the issue, which might be closely related to my problem as well. I have recently purchased Mac OS Studio (Monterey) with the maximum capacity so that I can do graph computations quickly. But many times when running Graph computations, Mathematica is either stuck or quits. I am really shocked!!! And it declares that MMA encountered problems. Since I am not a software person, I simply ignored the problems.

Comment: @Kassa: Maybe Mac OS for Mathematica has a problem because we have the same computer.

Comment: @Kassa: Can you check with your computer to send an open MMA worksheet by "Send To" in the menu? Whenever I use this function to send MMA notebooks by e-mail, my computer gets stuck, runs forever!!!

Comment: @TugrulTemel, FWIW, I can "Send To" without any problems on macOS Big Sur, Wolfram Desktop 13.2

Comment: @TugrulTemel, sending open MMA notebook through "Send To" didn't get stuck, but the email never arrives even though MMA claims the notebook has been sent.

Comment: @Kassa: Thanks for checking. I think there are certain issues with either Mac OS or MMA. I will contact MMA about it.

Comment: @Victor K: I tried many times to send and each time it looks like it is busy sending but never ending MMA. I had to force Quit.

Comment: @Kasa: and Victor K. I suppose that there are problems with "Graph" algorithms because I encounter problems of "never ending" calculation when I use `CommunityGraphPlot` `NeighborhoodGraph` etc. I also noticed that somehow retrieving data from an `Excel` worksheet takes a lot of time (4-5 minutes), given the power of my `Mac OS max M1` with 64 GB memory 32 GB CPU. This is really an unusual performance for this computer. I suspect that `Import` function of MMA also has weaknesses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is another possible way to eliminate the impact of history, etc. The following code aborts on my machine after printing to the console three times.

```
MemoryConstrained[
 Do[If[Mod[n, 2000] == 0, Print["mem ", MemoryInUse[]];];
  leakyFunction[12], {n, 10000}],
 10000000]
```

**Update.** It seems to be the `GraphAuthomorphismGroup` indeed:

```
g = RandomGraph[{12, RandomInteger[{0, 12 (12 - 1)/2}]}];

MemoryConstrained[
 Do[
  GraphAutomorphismGroup[g], {n, 40000}
  ],
 5000000]
```

gets aborted after a couple of seconds.

**Update 2.** To help Wolfram debug their graph functions for memory leaking, I created the following code, and I'm only half-joking :).

```
leakingQ[f_, args___] := 
 With[{before = MemoryInUse[]}, f[args]; MemoryInUse[] - before > 0]

name[f_Symbol] := f
name[fn_Function] := fn /. {Function[f_[___]] :> f}

leakingGraphFns[g_] := 
 Cases[Table[{name[f], 
    leakingQ[f, g]}, {f, {Graph, Graph3D, GraphAssortativity, 
     GraphAutomorphismGroup, GraphCenter, GraphComplement, 
     GraphDensity, GraphDiameter, GraphDifference[#, #] &, 
     GraphDisjointUnion[#, #] &, GraphDistance[#, 1, 20] &, 
     GraphDistanceMatrix, GraphEmbedding, GraphIntersection[#, #] &, 
     GraphJoin[#, #] &, GraphPeriphery, GraphPlot, GraphPlot3D, 
     GraphPower[#, 2] &, GraphProduct[#, #] &, GraphQ, GraphRadius, 
     GraphReciprocity, GraphSum[#, #] &, GraphTree, 
     GraphUnion[#, #] &}}], {x_, True} :> x]
    
Quiet@Union@Flatten@Table[leakingGraphFns[RandomGraph[{20, 100}]], 100]

(* {GraphAutomorphismGroup,GraphComplement,GraphDisjointUnion,
GraphPlot,GraphPower,GraphProduct,GraphTree} *)
```

It can also be turned into a regression test easily - just check that the expression above returns an empty list.